# Get latitude and longitude from address using Google Geocoding API error message: “you have exceeded your daily request quota for this api..”

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Here is my code**

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
```

How can I increase the quota. I have almost 30k+ data

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay for a [Google Maps license](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)